# How do I play a media file that I downloaded using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I would like to be able to download media files and play them, using Ajax. My approach (below) works fine for images - but for some reason the video files (AVI) won't play.

```
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
            if (type == 'Image') {
                document.getElementById("image_holder").src = "data:image/png;base64," + xmlhttp.responseText;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("video_holder").src = "data:video/avi;base64," + xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    };    
    xmlhttp.open("GET", server_url + '/get_file.php);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
```

HTML:

```
<video id="outer_video_holder">
            <source id="video_holder"  src="" type="video/avi">
        </video>
```

get_file.php

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE id=$file_id";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    header("Content-Type: video/avi");

    if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['content'];
    }
```

Comment: I would change your if else statement so that you do an else-if for the video type and then in your else put a message to tell you if it got there. anything could trigger the video source and cause an error

Comment: wouldn't set the src of the video source tag to the url of the file be enough to download it asynchronously (instead of setting the data:video/avi;base64, + responseText)?

Comment: @JonasGrumann - thanks. However I store the video/image file in a database and return its contents upon request.

Comment: what does get_file.php do?

Comment: Fetches the base64 encoded contents of the avi from the db and returns it. Updated the my post with it's code.